# Extracting some numbers from a short HTML snippet using regular expressions

Tags: python, regex

I have a string like below, and I want to get both the two number "28" and "1", but right now I can only get "28" by my code. Please help me with this.

```
import re
content="""<span class="lineNum">      28 </span><span class="lineCov">          1 : get_pid_file(const char *file, pid_t *pid)</span>"""
pattern = "(\d+)"
ret = re.search(pattern,content)
if ret:
   print "find: %s" % ret.group()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`re.findall`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall),

```
>>> re.findall(r"\d+", content)
['28', '1']
```

But you may want to narrow down your regex.

EDIT:

You may want to change your regular expression to some variation of `r"<span.*?>.*?(\d+).*?</span>"` to match only numbers inside span tags.

Comment: Thanks for your help, how to narrow down my regex, because maybe there will be number exist in other place, so i only want to get the number between <span> </span> and the number before :

Answer (score 0):

```
pattern = "(\d+).*(\d+)"
ret = re.search(pattern,content)
print ret.group(1), ret.group(2)
```